# Iterate rows base on its entries column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on SQL SELECT QUERY.

This is my TABLE.

```
id | name             | entries |
---------------------------------
1  | Jose Rizal       | 1       |
2  | Raffy Tulfo      | 2       |
3  | Cong TV          | 1       |
---------------------------------
```

I want to select get them like this

```
| name             |
--------------------
| Jose Rizal       |
| Raffy Tulfo      |
| Raffy Tulfo      |
| Cong TV          |
--------------------
```

If you can notice, `Raffy Tulfo` has 2 rows because it has 2 entries.

`

Comment: I think it is more practical not to do the logic in your select query, instead, do it in the actual implementation in the be.

Comment: @fmsthird Hi, May I know the pros and cons of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cte` to achieve this requirement if your `mysql` is version `8.0 up`. but if its below, 1 way to do this is using dummy values using `union`.

```
SELECT name
FROM test t1
    JOIN (
                SELECT 1 as number UNION
                SELECT 2 UNION
                SELECT 3 UNION
                SELECT 4 UNION
                SELECT 5 UNION
                SELECT 6 UNION
                SELECT 7 
         ) n
    ON t1.entries >= n.number
order by name;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=6dddnpj7pn)

Comment: Nice one, Thankyou. May I know the reference for CTE about this case?

Comment: @MONSTEEEER, for cte, you will also need recursive one. so you still use union